# The location of SharedPrecompileHeaders folders on XCode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, pch

I'm building my own SDK and got error about pch

```
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    ProcessPCH /var/folders/49/qmkbt97910v4p_h0f3c7ygzw0000gr/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.1.1-6A2008a/Xcode/6.1.1-6A2008a/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/VoxyPADFramework-Prefix-gfoeppzqeydinfdjwgglsszazzop/VoxyPADFramework-Prefix.pch.pch VoxyPADFramework/VoxyPADFramework-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    ProcessPCH /var/folders/49/qmkbt97910v4p_h0f3c7ygzw0000gr/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.1.1-6A2008a/Xcode/6.1.1-6A2008a/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/VoxyPADFramework-Prefix-dqgbxgrxhqfaflffhnvdflncjokz/VoxyPADFramework-Prefix.pch.pch VoxyPADFramework/VoxyPADFramework-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
```

As guide somewhere I have to remove the SharedPrecompileHeaders on Precompile Header Cache Path, but the path of it is

`var/folders/49/qmkbt97910v4p_h0f3c7ygzw0000gr/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.1.1-6A2008a/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders`

I can't find it anywhere on my Mac, how can I manually remove it